# ADF Session timeout automatic redirection without popup dialog

Tags: java, session, session-timeout, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

Is there a possibility to redirect automaticaly to another page after session timeout without the popup dialog?

See picture below
[image]

I saw this [How to automatically Redirect to Different Page on session timeout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGDevlbSLcw) which use javascript but it's not what i want. Is there another simple way? May be some settings in web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the web.xml you just need to make the settings below:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>
     oracle.adf.view.rich.sessionHandling.WARNING_BEFORE_TIMEOUT
  </param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [article](http://adfdevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/detecting-and-handling-user-session.html) and this [article](http://spikey-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/adf-faces-and-that-annoying-session.html). Create a filter to detect session timeout then redirect to a specific page.